# When do auto-layout constraints get applied to subviews of UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, autolayout

I have a custom UITableViewCell that has some constraints.  One of these constraints is to display a UIScrollView that fits within the bounds of the screen with a bit of a margin on one side.

These are the constraints on the scroll view:

[image]

So it should keep a 1:1 ratio with some trailing space.

Now, in `layoutSubviews` I setup some content in the scroll view:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    let pagesScrollViewSize = scrollView.frame.size
    print("SCROLL VIEW SIZE: \(scrollView.frame.size)")
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: pagesScrollViewSize.width * CGFloat(pageImageUrls.count),
        height: pagesScrollViewSize.height)
    loadVisiblePages()
}
```

The problem is that when this code first executes the frame of the scroll view is not yet at it's final size.  At first I get:

SCROLL VIEW SIZE: (380.0, 380.0)

and then later (presumably after the constraints are applied),

SCROLL VIEW SIZE: (300.0, 300.0)

So, how can I guarantee that the scroll view will be at its final size when I go to layout content?  At what point do these constraints actually get applied?

Thanks

Comment: In my opinion in both cases constraints are actually applied. The problem why you have different sizes is that cell is probably initialized with width 400; not because constraints are not applied.

Comment: Why would the cell get initialized with width 400?  And what causes that width to later change?

Comment: Could be size classes? I am not sure. But constraints must be applied for both calls, otherwise you can not get 1:1 for both calls.